# Full screen apps won't redraw after tabbing out - seeking help to fix or debug

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina, graphics

When running an app in any full screen mode, if I tab out, when I tab back in the app does not redraw.  The app menu bar shows and is responsive, so I can cmd-Q to quit, but nothing else redraws.  All the examples I'm seeing this with are Steam games, but that could just be because I don't run any other full screen apps on my Macbook.  I think it happens consistently for all full screen apps.  It is possible that all the apps in question are built on Unity.

Testing with Exocolonist game, redraw fails on all of exclusive full screen mode, full screen window mode, and maximized window mode.

Running macOS Catalina 10.15.7, fully up to date, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2GB and Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB, on 15-inch Retina mid 2015 MacBook Pro.

Any suggestions for fix or debug appreciated.  Thanks.

ETA: Just occurred to me to try a YouTube video in full screen (Firefox).  No problems tabbing out and back for that.  Notably, when tabbed out the video continues to show over my desktop with the app I tabbed into displayed over it, while with the games when I tab out the game disappears and shows my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I have just stumbled on the answer:  it was a Spaces issue.  Ticking "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application" under Mission Control preferences fixed the problem.  Never mind!